# Shadow is not on the correct position on oblique objects

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

At the beginning, the ball rolls on a flat object, after that, it rolls on an oblique object. On the flat object, the ball´s shadow is drawn on the correct position, but on oblique objects, the ball´s shadow is always on the wrong position. The shadow should be always in the middle under the ball.

When the ball is on the ground(flat object), then ShadowRotation = 0f.
When the ball is on the obstacle(oblique object), then ShadowRotation = -0.24f because the ascent of the obstacle is -0.24f.
The variable ShadowRotation is the only variable that I change when the ball is on an oblique object.

Why is the shadow not on the correct position when the ball rolls over an oblique object? Could anyone explain me what I´m doing wrong?

[image: Flat object]
[image: Oblique object]

```
Texture2D ShadowSprite, BallSprite, GroundSprite, ObstacleSprite;
float ShadowRotation;

spriteBatch.Draw(GroundSprite, new Vector2(GroundPosition.X, GroundPosition.Y), null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(GroundSprite.Width / 2.0f, GroundSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.10f);

spriteBatch.Draw(ObstacleSprite, new Vector2(ObstaclePosition.X, ObstaclePosition.Y), null, Color.White, 0, new Vector2(ObstacleSprite.Width / 2.0f, ObstacleSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.09f);

spriteBatch.Draw(ShadowSprite, new Vector2(BallPosition.X, BallPosition.Y + BallSprite.Height / 2.0f), null, Color.White, ShadowRotation, new Vector2(ShadowSprite.Width / 2.0f, ShadowSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.08f);

spriteBatch.Draw(BallSprite, new Vector2(BallPosition.X, BallPosition.Y), null, Color.White, BallRotation, new Vector2(BallSprite.Width / 2.0f, BallSprite.Height / 2.0f), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0.07f);
```

Comment: Looks right to me...  Is the light straight down?  The shadow extends out the further it goes.  On the ramp the left is further than the right.

Comment: Yes, the light is straight down.

Comment: Thanx :) I didn't know that the shadow looks like this if the ball rolls up a ramp.

Comment: It makes sense if you think about it, right now you see that the shadow align with the ramp lines.